# Form group static in bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

AM using bootstrap 3 for my python web application. I want to use the application in mobile devices also. but the input form fields are become responsive to the width of the device. I want in input field width to be static as in browser . please advice how to achieve this?

below is the html which am using

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">         
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2 pull-left">
      Add Timesheet Details
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8 text-center">
      <label class="control-label" for="timesheet_no">Time Sheet Number:01</label>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <form id="add_detail" class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" name="page">
          <div style="display:none;"><input id="csrf_token" name="csrf_token" type="hidden" value="1434973923##5ac019cd8821a1dfda978dde3710893c8b0ced33"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="repeat" id="dimdetail-fieldset">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class ="table-responsive">
                    <table id="table_id" class="wrapper table table-bordered">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                        <th class="col-md-2"><button type="button" class="add btn btn-primary pull-left" id="add_time"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>&nbsp Time</button></th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody class="container">
                        <tr class="success">
                          <th class="col-md-2">Project</th>
                          <th class="col-md-2">Total Hours</th>
                          <th class="col-md-2">TPI Inspector Name</th>
                          <th class="col-md-2">Inspection Type</th>
                          <th class="col-md-2">Remarks</th>
                          <th></th>
                        </tr>                     
                      <tr >
                        <td class="form-group  col-md-2">
                          <select class="form-control" id="timesheet_time_details-0-project_id" name="timesheet_time_details-0-project_id" style="width:100%"><option value="">-- please choose --</option>
                          <option value="12997">12997</option></select>

                        </td>
                        <td class="form-group  col-md-2">
                          <input class="form-control" id="timesheet_time_details-0-total_hours" name="timesheet_time_details-0-total_hours" type="text" value="10.0">

                        </td>
                        <td class="form-group  col-md-2">
                          <input class="form-control" id="timesheet_time_details-0-tpi_inspector_name" name="timesheet_time_details-0-tpi_inspector_name" type="text" value="Ram">

                        </td>
                        <td class="form-group  col-md-2">
                          <select class="form-control" id="timesheet_time_details-0-testmethod" name="timesheet_time_details-0-testmethod" style="width:100%"><option value="__None">-- please choose --</option><option selected value="1">UltraSonic Inspection</option></select>

                        </td>
                        <td class="form-group  col-md-2">
                          <textarea class="form-control" id="timesheet_time_details-0-remarks" name="timesheet_time_details-0-remarks" rows="3">ok</textarea>

                        </td>
                        <td class="col-md-1">
                          <button class="remove btn btn-danger" type="button" id=""><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></i> Delete</button>
                        </td>
                      </tr>

                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-md-12">   
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-10 pull-left">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save" name="Save"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></i>&nbsp Save</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Submit for Approval" name="Save"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></i>&nbsp Submit for Approval</button>
                        <button id="delete" class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Delete" name="Save"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>&nbsp Delete</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to remove responsiveness for only the form element?

Comment: for form fields like input select ..

Comment: In bootstrap, form field are always 100% width. It's the form container that have a fixed width (maybe using a grid layout)

Comment: please check the html

Answer (score 1):

Add the below css

```
  .form-control {width:150px} /*the width you want*/
```

make sure it renders after your bootstrap css. You are however getting rid of the responsiveness of the row that contains the inputs.

[here is a bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/eAVoq9A2YK)